# Getting wrong characters in pt-br from xml in python

Tags: python, xml, encoding

I'm trying to send data from a XML feed to MySQL database, but I'm getting wrong pt-br characters in python and mysql.

```
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
import sys
import codecs

## default enconding
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
UTF8Writer = codecs.getwriter('utf8')
sys.stdout = UTF8Writer(sys.stdout)
file = urllib2.urlopen('feed.xml')
data = file.read()
file.close()
data = xmltodict.parse(data)

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=MYSQL_HOST,    # your host, usually localhost
                     user=MYSQL_USER,         # your username
                     passwd=MYSQL_PASSWD,  # your password
                     db=MYSQL_DB)        # name of the data base
cur = db.cursor()

    product_name = str(data.items()[0][1].items()[2][1].items()[3][1][i].items()[1][1])
```

But when I print product_name in Python or insert it into mysql, I get this:

```
'Probi\xc3\xb3tica (120caps)'
```

this should be:

```
'Probiótica'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'Probi\xc3\xb3tica'` is the utf-8 encoded version of `'Probiótica'`.
Is your terminal (or whatever you are using to run this) set up to handle utf-8 output?
Try `print 'Probi\xc3\xb3tica'.decode('utf-8')` to see what happens.
I get `Probiótica`.

Comment: I get u'Probi\xf3tica'. I'm using OSx Terminal to code. How can I edit it to output the right characters?

Comment: I checked in Preference -> Advanced and my Text encode is Unicode (UTF-8)

Comment: In that case, I'd expect `print 'Probi\xc3\xb3tica'` to give `Probiótica` - that's what I get in a similar configuration.  My answer above shows what I get using Emacs to run Python.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting Probiótica now when I print as you said. But data coming from the XML still prints 'Probi\xc3\xb3tica'

Comment: You're looking at the `repr` of that data, which looks different than the way the data is interpreted (which is what `print` shows you).  If your data is supposed to be utf-8 encoded, it appears to be correct.